# javascript execution on button click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

I am designing an application which is using a predefined library from  `DataTables` to create the data table. I want to perform remove operation on Datatable, for which java script should get executed on button click event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        }
        else {
            table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    });

    $('#button').click(function() {
        table.row('.selected').remove().draw(false);
    });
});
```

HTML button is:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Remove</button>
```

Clicking this button should execute above script and the selected row should get deleted from the datatable.

Comment: by datatable do you mean to say you are using a jquery plugin datatables?

Answer (score 1):

You need set the `id`(identifier) of button since you are using [ID Selector ("#id")](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

```
<button id="button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Remove</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not actually selecting the right button .
ways to select

1>To select the button either add "id='button'" without quotes in the html or 2>user your class to select the button if it is unique.

though both will work, first one is recommended.